# Is it possible to subscribe to two different topics with a single call to topic.subscribe() in DOJO?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I would like to know if is it possible to subscribe to two different topics with a single call to [topic.subscribe()](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/#1_10dojo_topic_subscribe).

For example, I need to run `this._process(`) when topic`'event/a'` and `'event/b'` are published. At the moment I am using the following code, but I would like to know if would be possible use a single call to `topic.subscribe()` instead.

Unfortunately looking at the documentation seems only one parameter for `topic.subscribe()` is allowed.

Do you know how any work around? Or is it possible to extend the functionalities to subscribe to accommodate this?

```
        topic.subscribe('event/action/a', function () {
            this._process();
        }.bind(this));
        topic.subscribe('event/action/b', function () {
            this._process();
        }.bind(this));
```

Comment: As far as i can tell its just 1 parameter.  you can loop the topic.subscribe if you have a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

I recall that I could do something similar of what you are after with joining the events you are subscribing to into an array

```
topic.subscribe(['event/action/a', 'event/action/b'], callback);
```

I've looked it up in the source code (for dojo/on) and it should support the arrays. Apologies if I'm wrong.